# retrieve data from sql where start date is equal and between end date

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

i got a table that stores `start_date` and `end_date` with the field type `DATE`

I want to retrieve all records between the `start_date` and `end_date` but my below SQL statement do not give any results.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM expo Where date >= DATE(NOW()) AND end_date <= DATE(NOW())";
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [between](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_between) function to perform this action.

```
SELECT * 
FROM expo 
WHERE NOW() BETWEEN date AND end_date
```

Oh, since your column is `date`, not `datetime` use `date(now())`. That will select records that start and end on the current date as well.

Demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0aaad/6

```
SELECT * 
FROM expo 
WHERE date(NOW()) BETWEEN date AND end_date
```

Comment: watch that other guy complain that their answer was first (I sure hope they don't). Got my vote Chris ;-)

Comment: btw if between is used, it does not show the record of current date.. example, my start date and end date is the same, it does not show any record @KostasMitsarakis

Answer (score 0):

Use `curdate`

```
SELECT * 
FROM expo 
WHERE date >= curdate() AND end_date <= curdate()
```